# Android Broadcast Receiver keeping a POJO alive in Memory forever?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver, android-memory

I have a broadcast receiver class that detects incoming calls.

When the app is turned off, all data in "CallHistory" POJO class is lost (As it should).

When a call is received during the time the app is OFF, the receiver inserts the current time in a **static** array in my POJO class then to the DB. (All fine till now)

However, when I launch the app and get the array size, it still has the added element(s) by the broadcast receiving method when the app was OFF!

1) Why is my POJO class data surviving after the work of the broadcast receiving method is completed and my app is  OFF? How can I fix that memory leak?

2) Can the ViewModel architecture component fix that? But, I think it will make it worse in this case as the broadcastReceiver unlike an Activity is always running.

Comment: you can clear the list when you launch app.

Comment: @AliAhmed Of course, but that doesn't fix the memory leak. Plus what if i was storing bigger data not just time strings? Will they just remain in memory for no reason?

Comment: static variables should be cleared manually after use.

Comment: @Khemraj You mean after use through a broadcast receiver when the app is off? Because that's the only case it just stays alive. I am confused.

Comment: Yes, when you code does not need static pojo anymore, then make that null. By the way you can also ignore using static fields. that are always causing memory leaks.

Comment: @Khemraj Thank you. I have an extra question for you :) 
 Google made the ViewModel component to fix the issue of data loss of java classes when rotating the device causing activity to be destroyed then recreated. If static variables survive then why was that a problem in the first place?

Comment: ViewModel are not just introduced to save states, which was already there. There are lot of benefits of using Android Jetpack. You should understand the use cases here. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/